# how to insert a GitHub linked data for my experimental results in a research paper?

Tags: engineering, license, databases

I have wondered about the policy of insert a **GitHub link** in my technical note to make the all benchmarks results available. Is there any license required ?  or a specific format?

example:
https://rana-elkhouly.github.io/poblemname/
Field: Operations Research/Industrial Engineering

Comment: This is probably going to be field dependent, can you name a field?

Comment: A github.io link, like in your example, is simply a web page. Why do you need to treat it differently from any other web page? Or did you mean a GitHub *repository* link?

Comment: A link ending with github.io is a [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) link, and is their static website hosting service. It simply allows hosting any web pages you want. A GitHub repository, on the other hand, is code that is hosted (e.g. by you) on github.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit surprised this isn't duplicated somewhere.

In terms of the data's technical format (e.g. file formats, directory structure, etc.), that's usually going to depend substantially on the culture in your field and what reviewers will accept.

In terms of how to host data you'd like to be publicly available: Before your paper is accepted, even just a link to a GitHub repository in the body of a preprint is probably sufficient for review purposes. Once a paper's accepted, my personal experience is that journals which care about data and software access at all encourage that a paper's auxiliary software and data be hosted via a service with archival intent rather than GitHub's expressly commercial mission.

In the latter case there are several services available- I don't think it's sensible to attempt an extensive list. You could consider [Zenodo](https://about.zenodo.org/policies/) as a single example that's operational at time-of-writing to illustrate the theme and search for others. If you're at a university, your current institution may also offer a similar service.

As far as licensing is concerned: Academia.SE as a policy typically doesn't wade into extensive legal advice. So let me put it this way: For any data or software whose copyright you own or manage, I've found it pragmatically easiest to license via some form of open source license. That way any reviewers or readers can access that information freely without think about it too hard.

I've never seen nor heard about an academic publication venue requesting copyright for auxiliary data or software associated with a publication.